# Stylistic convention when adding functions to JS prototypes

Tags: javascript, prototype

As far as I can tell, there is no functional difference in JavaScript between adding multiple functions to an object's prototype like this:

```
MyObject.prototype.myFunction = function() {
    return this.foo + this.bar;
}
MyObject.prototype.otherFunction = function() {
    return this.foo * this.bar;
}
```

or this:

```
MyObject.prototype = {
    myFunction: function() {
        return this.foo + this.bar;
    },
    otherFunction: function() {
        return this.foo * this.bar;
    }
}
```

Is there any reason to use one over the other? To me, the second option is cleaner because all function declarations sit "inside" of the prototype in terms of indentation. This seems to mostly be a question of style; is there a convention that is followed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
 MyObject.prototype = { }
```

will override previously defined methods, properties and inheritance. So you might use

```
Object.assign(MyObject.prototype, {
   /*...*/
});
```

then. I prefer keeping all the prototype methods together so i would go with this variant instead of just assigning every method on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the first option in all of the cases, because it's more extendable and error-proof. In first case you are adding to the prototype of MyObject, in the second one you are overriding it.